# PMD validation for "x!=y"

Tags: java, pmd

Here is my code:

```
private void showMessageForInvalid(File aFile) {
  if (!aFile.exists()) {
     // show not exists message
  } else if (!aFile.isDirectory()) {
     // show not directory message
  }
}
```

For the first if block I get a PMD warning "Avoid x!=y else". I think, this warning would be correct in case

```
if (!aFile.exists()) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do else
}
```

But not in my case with `else if` statement. 
Is this a PMD bug or is this warning correct (how should I write code in such cases)?

Comment: This is probably because of pmd thinks that positive result should come first in `if else` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @Tim B's answer:

It's listed under [Design rules as 'confusing ternary'](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3/rules/design.html).

It's in general bad to have `!condition` in `if-else` blocks. In most cases, it's due to bad structuring:

```
if(healthy)
     business-logic
else
     error-handling
```

The above is what *most* (admittedly not everyone) people find as their natural line of thought, rather than

```
if(!healthy)
     error-handling first
else
     business-logic later
```

Now, this is not always the case - and your function, which is (implied in its name) explicitly handling an error case - is one of the possible exceptions. Unfortunately, with a static code analysis tool like PMD you can either catch all cases or catch none - and in this case the developers chose to go with all; admittedly making it a bit overzealous.

Anyway, this is the reason that it's listed under PMD's design rules. When encountered with cases like this, I find it easiest to just specify [a ruleset exclusion as described here](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.1.1/howtomakearuleset.html), rather than actually modify the source code to something which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Thank you for answer. This was what I want to know. About your example: it's good and correct but in some cases I get a null value when something goes wrong and write the error handling before the business logic.

Answer (score 3):

Do the exists branch first:

```
if (aFile.exists()) {

   if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
       // Do stuff
   } else {
       // show not directory message
   }    
} else {
   // show not exists message
}
```

This has the same actual program flow and logical structure but it is much clearer "at a glance" what is happening.

Comment: I think your approach is not better than mine

Comment: In your approach it's not immediately obvious that the "not a directory" message is dependent on the directory existing. That's why the code is considered less readable and you get the warning. The structure I suggested will most likely not trigger the PMD warning and once you put code in `Do stuff` it will be immediately clear. Especially since in your original example you generated the error message but still went on and executed your code (unless the message also exited the method).

Comment: Debatable not better style, but the PMD thinks it is. Switching `if (!C) A else B` with `if (C) B else A`. PMD overshot its target here.

Comment: @JoopEggen For what it's worth I agree there's not much in it style wise. I wouldn't have complained about the original code in a code review for example.